# Why does time() differ from a date time object

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I'm slightly confused what's going on. I created a variable that stores the result of time() and I created a DateTime object with parameters  "now", and new DateTimeZone and set it to mine. Next I used the getTimestamp method on the DateTime objects. I echoed both the time() and the DateTime timestamp out. They were both the same. When I went to store it in a cookie. They gave me very different times. The time method was correct but the DateTime ended up with year 2069. Anyone know what's going on?

Code

```
$time = time();
$datetime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
$datetime = $datetime->getTimestamp();
echo $time."<br />";
echo $datetime;

setcookie("T1","Time1",$time);
setcookie("T2","Time2",$datetime);
```

Comment: Could you please show your code, and maybe also mention what your timezone is? Quite hard to say without seeing what you are actually doing :)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your Problem is that the line with `$datetime = new DateTime...` seems to deliver a DateTime object with a timestamp from 2069. How exactly did you check it? I can not reconstruct it, see here: https://eval.in/504808 - If you get a very weird date with this indeed: Did you check if your system clock is extremely off?